# Calculating the weighted moving average of 2 lists using a set window

Tags: kdb

If I have two lists:

```
a:1 2 3 4;
b:10 20 30 40;
```

I want to sum the product of the two lists within a window of 2.  So the result set should be:

```
10 50 130 250
```

For example, to get the result of 130 it would be (2*20)+(3*30) = 130

```
sums 2 mavg '(a*b)
```

seems to get me part way there, but the window of 2 isn't being applied.  I've tried experimenting with `sum`, `sums`, `sum each`, `wavg`, `mavg`, etc. and I am completely stuck.  Could anyone help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could use the adverb each prior:

```
q)+':[a*b]
```

However this will only work with a window size of 2 and if your data contains null values this needs to be padded with 0:

```
q)+':[0^a*b2]
```

On a positive note it is faster than using msum in this situation.

```
q)\ts:1000000 +':[0^a*b2]
940 1264
q)\ts:1000000 2 msum a*b2
1556 1104
```

Comment: It would probably be more legible to use the `prior` keyword, either infix `(+)prior a*b` or prefix `prior[+;a*b]`

Answer (score 5):

This line should work for you:

`2 msum a*b`

as demonstrated here:

```
q)a:1 2 3 4
q)b:10 20 30 40
q)2 msum a*b
10 50 130 250
```

For more information about the keyword `msum`, you could check out the Kx Reference page:
https://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/msum

Hope that helps!